# Liquibase lib file has console.log which prints the DB credentials. Please find the line#47 of the attached liquibase lib file. how to stop it?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

```
const LiquibaseTS = require('node-liquibase').Liquibase;
const POSTGRESQL_DEFAULT_CONFIG = require('node-liquibase').POSTGRESQL_DEFAULT_CONFIG;

const myConfig = {
  ...POSTGRESQL_DEFAULT_CONFIG,
  changeLogFile: './changelog.xml',
  url: 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/node_liquibase_testing',
  username: 'postgres',
  password: 'postgres123',
  logLevel: 'info'
}

const instTs = new LiquibaseTS(myConfig);
instTs.update();
```

I've the above code in my index.js file.
I get the below console output when the line instTs.update(); get executed,

*Running /Users/path1/path2/sampleapp/node_modules/node-liquibase/dist/liquibase/liquibase --changeLogFile="./changelog.xml" --url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost" --username="Postgres" --password="postgres123" --classpath="/Users/path1/path2/sampleapp/node_modules/node-liquibase/dist/drivers/postgresql-42.2.8.jar" --logLevel="info" update ...*

when I debug the *node-liquibase* library I found that this console print is due to the line#47 of the file */Users/path1path2/sampleapp/node_modules/node-liquibase/dist/node-liquibase.cjs.development.js*

the code snippet in the *node-liquibase.cjs.development.js* file is,

```
 CommandHandler.spawnChildProcess = function spawnChildProcess(commandString) {
    console.log("Running " + commandString + "...");
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      child_process.exec(commandString, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log('\n', stdout);

        if (error) {
          console.error('\n', stderr); // error.stderr = stderr;

          return reject(error);
        }

        resolve(stdout);
      });
    });
  };

  return CommandHandler;
}();
```

as per that file, the line# 47 is very first line of the function

```
console.log("Running " + commandString + "...");
```

This code is printing the DB details/credentials in the console. Also I noticed that liquibase prints the DB details/credentials on the console along with the error for the changeset error scenario.

What I need?

1. I want to stop printing the DB credentials on the console during normal run.
2. During error scenario, I want only the liquibase error printed on the console. it should not print the error with db credentials on the console.
3. index.js code *instTs.update();* is not throwing any exception during error scenario. How can we find/distinguish the error scenario. eg: changeset to insert a value where the table doesn't exist.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: Are you saying your command string has credentials in it?

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks, I've edited the original post with more details to give you more context. Can you pls take a look and let me know if you need any more info?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid
command string has credentials in it?- yes.

Answer (score 0):

Since it prints out the configuration, your only option is probably to move the sensitive information to another spot liquibase can read configuration from.

If you make a liquibase.properties file with your password in it, I don't think that will show in the logs. I've not used the node-liquibase frontend much, so I don't know if you need to explicitly add a `liquibasePropertiesFile` setting to your config.

Alternately, if you use a newer version of liquibase (probably newer than what node-liquibase ships with by default, but there is a way to override that with the `liquibase` argument) you can set the password and other fields with environment variables as well, and those will not be logged.

Comment: It would be best to not be logging passwords from the config too without needing either of these options. PRs to improve functionality are always appreciated

Comment: Thanks for your response. Here are my observations, 1) I'm using the latest version of node-liquibase lib. 2) This is nothing to do with liquibasePropertiesFile or with env variables because this is purely related to console.log and console.error statements used in the above stated lib file. 3) We should avoid supplying the sensitive DB info to "commandString", "stdout" and "stderr" in the above stated file.

Comment: I use 4.1.1 version of node-liquibase.

Comment: Yeah, the console.log and console.err statements above are what need to be fixed. I'm just trying to find some work-arounds and options until someone is able to build a fix.

Comment: One more thing needs to be fixed. instTs.update(); not throwing any error/exception when there is any error in the changeset. Eg: inserting a record in a table which doesn't exist.